USDC moved from my Phantom Wallet without my authorisation
I transferred funds from my bank account to Phantom Wallet via Moonpay and it is showing in my Phantom Wallet as just USD - which Phantom Wallet are saying is fake and my balance is 0.
Moonpay have said to send these two transaction receipts as they are saying the funds were transferred correctly in full from my bank account to a correct Phantom Wallet. I have attached the receipts that show the correct transactions.
I have been speaking with Moonpay who have been very helpful and assured me they transferred the funds as per the details below into a correct wallet and someone has transferred them out as per the second transaction.
The first transaction shows where my money went via Moonpay to Phantom Wallet and was received correctly as USDC Sol.
https://solscan.io/tx/4YVakYVFUsPH8vrzyFeTrWVGkKUY1i52sii5GGAvnQzLQ9C6R3zKGsN3sGmBc71WUUh6WS52kSchaPVvoXNtRHUS
They said there was a second transaction where someone has transferred my USDC out of my wallet and replaced it with a fake USD currency which has no value. This is the transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/5GoU5evk6FSqWcEbLzP542JGEqKattTskuz1JD8hBBNoV9w9fJSDWb8sHJ8DFCg99CcoxJoei2VtSG9YoFn29P11
I did all the transactions myself and have not given anyone my details/passwords/logins or any information that could allow a scam to occur. My codes etc are all written down and not on my phone or computer.
I am not getting much help from Phantom Wallet.... Any suggestions about how I track down where this has gone and how I can get my money back?
Thank you,
Lucy

From looking at the transactions you sent it seems you received USDC from the address (H3aZbPJV9qLGP9E3rTSE3oxEWKYKNiH2LuLgV7Q4TDRr) and almost immediately after also received another transfer of (+0.005541185 Sol) from (HSyhSiQ23KJpABYZeriGG4LDoXe39nmc6G7cxeAUDRDA) address and somehow your USDC and Sol was transfered to this same wallet. If you did not sign the transaction to transfer the tokens to this address then it's most likely a scam
